# An item with the same key has already been added when registering controller without a specific constructor signature

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

This is really odd. Have an MVC 5 application using Autofac 3.3 that throws the `An item with the same key has already been added` error when I add a new controller that doesn't have specific constructor signatures.

How do I go about debugging this?

If the constructor looks like the following then when I navigate to the url for that controller it loads fine:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceManager _serviceManager;

    public ProductController(IServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        _serviceManager = serviceManager;
    }
 }
```

But if I add a new controller with no constructor, a parameter-less constructor, or various other signatures and navigate to that specific url it explodes:

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    // explodes
    public QuestionController()
    {
    }
    // explodes
    public QuestionController(DbContext ctx)
    {
    }
    // loads fine
    public QuestionController(IServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
    }
    // loads fine
    public QuestionController(AnonymousIdentityHandler handler)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm doing this in my registration for Autofac:

```
 builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +10933453
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +23
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) +161
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +132
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
   Autofac.Core.Registration.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +19
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +74
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +53
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringPropertyInjector.InjectProperties(IComponentContext context, Object instance, Boolean overrideSetValues) +594
   Autofac.Builder.<>c__DisplayClassd.<PropertiesAutowired>b__c(Object s, ActivatingEventArgs`1 e) +32
   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivating(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +73
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +128
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +24
   Autofac.Core.Registration.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +19
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +44
```

**Autofac registrations:**

```
builder.RegisterType<WebApiContext>().As<DbContext>().Named<DbContext>("WebApiContext").InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MainContext>().As<DbContext>().Named<DbContext>("MainContext").InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<ServiceManager>().As<IServiceManager>().Named<IServiceManager>("OneTime").InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceManager>().As<IServiceManager>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<SecurityConfig>().AsSelf().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterType<apiController>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<DbContext>("WebApiContext")).InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

// controllers
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
// allows injection into custom WebViewPage
builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

// various
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUser>().AsSelf().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousIdentityHandler>().AsSelf().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceBase>().AsSelf().InstancePerHttpRequest().PropertiesAutowired();

// register all entity repositories
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();

// services
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Product).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);

// paging stuff
builder.RegisterType<PagedProduct>().As<IPagedProduct<ProductForSearchResult>>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<Pager>().As<IPager>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PagedList<>)).InstancePerDependency();

// mvc action method injection.
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();

// http abstractions
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

IContainer container = builder.Build();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

return container;
```

---

**Update 1**

I was able to step into the Autofac code and discovered that Autofac is attempting to add the same key twice during `GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func<object> creator)` call. I'm not sure how to fix this though. I only have one call to register that type. Perhaps a threading bug with autofac?

```
+       this    {Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope}   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope
+       id  {3dc68c6e-60f2-4318-8975-6eb68ce82f3f}  System.Guid
+       creator {Method = {System.Object <Execute>b__0()}}  System.Func<object>
+       obj2    {SR.Data.Security.ApplicationUser}  object {SR.Data.Security.ApplicationUser}
```

Comment: How do you resolve your controllers?

Comment: I don't, the MVC framework does whatever it does to materialize the controllers. Autofac somehow hooks into the materialization process and injects the dependencies.

Comment: What other registrations are you making in the container? Any chance it's not the controller causing the issue, but the controller access just what causes the issue to surface?

Comment: Yes, could you show us other registrations please, especially that made via delegates or resolving from IComponentContext or resolving with parameters. Seems like you have a circular dependency and avoid it by resolving a dependency with parameter somewhere.

Comment: @TravisIllig, I've added the autofac registrations to the bottom. Anything look fishy there?

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin, I've added the autofac registrations to the bottom. Anything look fishy there?

Comment: The following line looks fishy "builder.RegisterType<ServiceManager>().As<IServiceManager>().Named<IServiceManager>("OneTime").InstancePerDependency();" Please check the places where you resolve the named registration. It should be somewhere in ServiceManager's dependencies tree.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin, it was an artifact from something long ago. Commented it out and still have the error. I attempted to step into the autofac code using Reflector.Net and I think its trying to add the *ApplicationUser* twice in the *GetOrCreateAndShare()* method. I'm no 100% sure though because Visual Studio can't get all of the variable values because I don't have the autofac pdb's. Trying to figure out how to get a hold of those now for further debugging.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin, check out update 1.

Comment: @TravisIllig, check out update 1.

Comment: The flow could be: 1. Autofac is resolving ApplicationUser 2. Autofac is resolving ApplicationUser's dependency tree 3. One of them has ApplicationUser as a dependency. So you have a circular dependency here. You resolve ApplicationUser somehow, ie explicitly with parameters. Autofac added ApplicationUser to dictionary. 4. The dependency tree is resolved 5. Autofac tries to add ApplicationUser to dictionary where it already exists - exception.

Comment: Could you post simplified reproducible example please.

Comment: I've replicated this issue as well.  However it's only happened once in the debugger

Comment: I've added the details of the exception I received here.... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500529/autofac-exception-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added

Comment: This issue is also tracked here: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/567