# Autofac - Exception: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac

I've just switched over to Autofac and it seems to be working well.  However I've received one disconcerting error message whilst debugging the application.  However I've since not been able to replicate it.  I think this has something to do with a multithreading race condition.

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> An item with the same key has already been added. (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
   at Tuna.TunaKernel.Get[T]() in S:\Tuna\TunaKernel.cs:line 32
```

In case you're wondering what TunaKernel looks like...

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tuna
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class used for providing instances of classes to Tuna applications 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Wrapper around Autofac IOC solution</remarks>
    public class TunaKernel : ITunaKernel
    {
        ILifetimeScope _container;

        /// <summary>
        /// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="TunaKernel"/> class from being created.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modules">The modules.</param>
        public TunaKernel(ILifetimeScope container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an instance of T
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The object to get an instance of</typeparam>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Get<T>() 
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

The binding for the item was

```
builder.RegisterType<EditProgramHelper>().As<IEditProgramHelper>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And yes I realise using the scope directly like this is not advised, however I'm dealing with a large amount of code that is already written.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176210/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-when-registering-controller-wit

However there is no answer to this question and my stack trace is slightly different

Comment: It seems like a multithreading race condition for me, as you mentioned. .NET Dictionary is not thread-safe for writing operations, and the stack trace states Autofac tries to add a specific key twice.  But it's very hard to say how to fixed, when it's almost impossible to replicate, as you wrote...

Comment: I've posted an answer to the other question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176210/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-when-registering-controller-wit

which i think will solve the problem.  Inspecting the code I can see that it's extremely unlikely this problem will occur but not impossible.  The code change I've suggested to Autofac will make it impossible.

Comment: Scratch that had another look and I can't see how two threads get access to the LifetimeScope's _sharedInstances dictionary.  Although I don't think it would hurt to change the type of _sharedInstances from Dictionary to ConcurrentDictionary